# Simplistic Processing code not working

Tags: processing

So I'm just trying to replicate this for starters.
https://processing.org/examples/setupdraw.html

It tells me "unexpected token: int".
So how the frick...
Like I got the book "Getting Started with Processing."
Its got some good stuff.  But i still can't figure out why this doesn't work.
Can you not establish a variable in the set up?

```
void setup() {

  size(1000, 1000);
  background(0);
  stroke(255)
  int line1 = 100;
}

void draw() {

  line1 = line1 -1;
  if (line1 < 0){
    line1 = height;
  }
  line(0, line1, width, line1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semicolon missing issue. Best practice is Just remove the statement `int line1 = 100;` and put it as global, outside the methods as below

```
int line1 = 100;

void setup() {

 size(1000, 1000);
 background(0);
 stroke(255);
}

void draw() {

  line1 = line1 -1;
  if (line1 < 0){
    line1 = height;
  }
  line(0, line1, width, line1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tone.
I'm not sure where i would have ended up reading that.
Should i delete this post?

Comment: No need to delete this post. Still many people will come with the same issue and they can make use of this solution. That is what SO is for.

Comment: Oh ok cool.  Cause the last time i posted something that ended up being a stupid question, got some down votes.

Comment: Declaring variables inside methods is fine (not in this case though: `line1` is used in the `draw()` method). The source of the error is that you're missing a semicolon after `stroke(255)`. Any code after this line (in either version) will produce an error.